# Can I run a command WITHIN another command?

Tags: command-line, bash, twitter

Can I run a command within another command for example:

```
twidge update date
```

`date` being the bash command `date` so effectively, `twidge` will update twitter with today's date. `twidge` is a CLI based twitter client.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can try escaping the command like so

```
twidge update "$(date)"
```

Which will execute `date` and [concatenate the output of the command](http://twitter.com/#!/marcoceppi/status/27411071333) into the `twidge` command.

According to the `twidge` help info

> You can also omit the status, in which case a single line will be read
>   from stdin and taken as your update.  Example:
>
> `date | twidge update`

Just pipe the command to twidge via stdin.

Answer (score 16):

Yep, if I understand you properly, this will do it:

```
twidge update `date`
```

If `twidge` doesn't like it, try `twidge update "$(date)"`, quotation marks to pass it in as one long string.

Comment: Ah drats, twidge didn't like it, but thank you anyway, this information will prove useful later on no doubt.

Comment: The use of \`\` is deprecated, but anyway, if you prefer to use it you can do "\`date\`"